# I'm trying to create a Carousel for my website, however the images are just static, on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Bootstrap Plugins</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  </head>
  <body>

          <br><br>

          <!-- Bootstrap Carousel -->
          <div id="bestCarsCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                      <img src="../Images/project1a.jpg" alt="project1a" height ="300" width="400">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Car 1</h3>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                      <img src="../Images/project1b.jpg" alt ="project1b" height ="300" width="400">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Car 2</h3>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                      <img src="../Images/project1c.jpg" alt="project1c" height ="300" width="400">
                      <div class="carousel-caption" >
                          <h3>Car 3</h3>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              </a>
          </div>

          <br><br>



      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The thing is though, this code works perfectly fine, in my university's tutorial, where I got the code from, I've taken snippets from the code, and edited it to match my images, and I have the exact same jquery, and bootstrap codes, but in the tutorial it works fine, but in my own code it doesn't, and I don't understand why?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<br><br>
<!-- Bootstrap Carousel -->
<div id="bestCarsCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="../Images/project1a.jpg" alt="project1a" height ="300" width="400">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h3>Car 1</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <img src="../Images/project1b.jpg" alt ="project1b" height ="300" width="400">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h3>Car 2</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <img src="../Images/project1c.jpg" alt="project1c" height ="300" width="400">
    <div class="carousel-caption" >
     <h3>Car 3</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bestCarsCarousel" data-slide="next">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: what error you are getting in Console ?

Comment: See, there is no specific error, but the problem, is when I run the code, in cloud 9, the live preview doesn't match the tutorial carousel, it just has the numbers 1,2,3 on top of each other, with the images on top of each other, if I knew how to add an image I could show you

Comment: What specifically did you change from the "working" version?  Are the JavaScript and CSS resources loading correctly?  Specifically what mechanism produces the "carousel" effect and where exactly is that mechanism failing?

Comment: I agree you should see some kind of error in `console` or `network` tabs of your developer's console...

Comment: code works fine,http://www.bootply.com/Poa0AJ0QxN you must not be linking your js/css files correctly

Comment: ^^^ That would be my first guess

Comment: ok, you were right on the point the css file wasn't being called correctly, I changed the href="css/bootstrap.css" and added "../" to the front and it has now turned into the correct layout of a carousel, however the carousel itself still doesn't move, I tried the same thing with the jQuery, and bootstrap scripts that made no difference

Comment: I would like to change that as well, due to the "js" being within another folder called "javascript" it wasn't being called correctly, I removed it from the js folder and put it in the javascript folder, and now works to perfection, even though it was small errors, I'm glad you guys helped out! :)